# How would we classify the phrase "worn out?"

Tags: adjectives

How would we classify the phrase "worn out?" I know it can belong to the verb figure of speech, but here I'm interested in the usage where it seems to function as an adjective.

*He put on his worn out shoes.*

Sorry, I'm a bit confused as to whether I should include a hyphen as well. 
I'm guessing that there is some kind of classification for this. I know we have compound nouns, is there a compound adjective or a phrasal adjective?

Answer (score 2):

> **Wear** is a verb (though not solely a verb).
>
> **Worn** is its past participle (*I have worn shoes like this for thirty years*).
>
> But **worn** also exists as a (participial) adjective: *The worn parts
>   of the tyre look rather dangerous. This blanket is looking rather worn.*

Similarly

> **Wear out** is a (transitive or intransitive) multi-word verb [[Usingenglish.com](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/phrasal-verbs/wear+out.html); they use the term 'phrasal verb']: *You have worn out his patience* (can also be separable). My shoes have
>   *worn out*.
>
> ...
>
> **Worn out** can also be used as a (compound) participial adjective: *He put on
>   his worn out shoes* (often unhyphenated; see example given by [Collins Thesaurus](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/worn+out)). *My shoes are worn out.* (almost always unhyphenated in predicative position).

Comment: You beat me to it. I had to abandon my post midway. Anyway, upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Edwin's post is informative. `Worn out` is a participal adjective.

There's just one thing I'd like to add:

It is (usually) hyphenated if it is used before a noun. It is (usually) not hyphenated otherwise.

From [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/worn-out):

> - These shoes are worn out.
> - the gradual replacement of worn-out equipment
> - a speech full of worn-out old clichés